# How to repeat Python function N times with its results and keep some data between runs

Tags: python, function

I have very basic programming skills. I searched StackOverflow, but didn't find a suitable answer or couldn't adapt other answers. I made a function that works just fine for one set of parameters. It takes two parameters: `x` is a list of items and `y` is a list of items.

```
x = [item1, item2, item3, ...]
y = [item1, item2, item3, ...]
```

It returns a list with lists of items like `x` or `y`.

```
result = [
[item1, item2, item3, ...],
[item1, item2, item3, ...],
...
]
```

It also has two lists inside: `result` for aggregating unique results and `seen` for checking for duplicates.

```
def function(x,y)
    result = []
    seen = []
    for i in x:
       for j in y:
         raw_data = #some calculations between i and j
         data_to_check = #some other calculations
         if data_to_check not in raw_data:
            result.append(data_to_check)
            seen.append(raw_data)
   return result
```

Not super accurate but I think you got an idea. Now I need to send `result` back to that function in place of `x` and make calculations for every element in `result`, then send that new `result` back again, and do that over and over N times. Like this:

```
results = function(x,y) #first iteration
next_results = []
for result in results:
   next_results += function(result,y) #second iteration
next_results2 = []
for result in next_results:
   next_results2 += function(result,y) #third iteration?
```

Then I discovered that `next_results` has duplicates in it cause `seen` is only kept for one `result` while iterating. I need it to collect `raw_data` for whole run and cleared before next level.

So how to properly extend my function to level N, without making more and more `for` loops? Guess I need some new function that will call my function N times. Something like this? How to do it properly and keep `seen` for whole run?

```
def function_n(???,n)
    for ? in range(n):
       function(???)

    return final_results
```

My other thought was to modify my function to accept a list of lists as its first argument. But my function is quite complicated (to me) with many `if`s and `for`s based on input `x` and `y` so I can't figure out how to do that too. And how to make it work for first iteration while `x` is just a list and not a list of lists?

Comment: I think `recursion` is the term to read about in this case

Comment: @Gameplay, Recursion is hard to understand, but I'll try. Guess this means I have to modify my main function and call itself again somewhere near end, right? Then I also need to deal with first argument `x` so function can accept both normal list or list of lists.